# Index was outside the bounds of the array. how to do

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-table

check this link i am using this way to insert datafrom gridview to sql :

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Dynamic-TextBox-values-in-GridView-to-SQL-Server-Database.aspx

now i am getting error on insert portion please help????????

```
private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        string[] splitItems = null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {

            string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Tb_FamilyData (FormNo,Name,ITSNo,Age,Relation) VALUES";
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3], splitItems[4]);
            }

        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormNo", txts);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtsrno.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITSNo", txtyrprchs.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtyrprchs.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relation", txtyrprchs.Text);
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

or please guide me any other way to insert data from htmltable or asptable to sql database

Comment: The issue must be somewhere here `splitItems[4], splitItems[5]` on this array, but you are the only one that you can debug that program step by step to see where is that out side of the bound - or on some other point. So step by step debug your code to fix it. On the example I see only 3 items added to this array.

Comment: What is your `item` look like? Are you sure it's five comma separated values?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `splitItems` has less than 5 items, although you try to access it.

Before using `splitItems` check the length:

```
if (splitItems != null && splitItems.Length > 4)
{
    // use the array
}
```

Comment: Thank You So much it now saying record saved successfully but no data inserted in sql

Comment: Did you in comment `            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`? Does it get there?

Comment: Sorry My Mistake . I removed the comment but now it is saying "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized "

Comment: please check the Code Below

Comment: Your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` only gets called when there are enough items. Ensure there are at least 5.